# Google maps api(v3) doesn't show markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am working with google maps api(v3) and i have to add markers on a map.
Actually, I had no problem with displaying them or whatever but after a while the markers started not to be displayed or more precisly, they are displayed from time to time.

Here is some code so you can see what i'm doing and where the problem could come from:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[KEY]&sensor=true"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="google.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="dataLoading.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="initializeMaps();">
        <div id="map_canvas"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            loadSpots();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the javascript code:

```
var map;
var yMarker = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow-dot.png';
var gMarker = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png';
var bMarker = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png';
var pMarker = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/pink-dot.png';

function initializeMaps()
{
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var mapOptions =
{
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(46.52863469527167, 2.4389648437),
    zoom: 6,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    mapOptions);
}

function getLatlng(address, name, type)
{
geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
    {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            title: name,
            map: map,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
        marker.setIcon((type == 2 ? gMarker : (type == 3 ? bMarker : (type == 4 ? pMarker : yMarker))));
    }
});
}

function addMarker(address, name, type)
{
if (address != null && address != "")
    getLatlng(address, name, type);
}
```

**EDIT1**

LoadSpots() is a function that gets data from DB with an ajax request and then calls addMarker function

Comment: How many markers do you try to add when the issue occurs?

Comment: It was working with dozens of them but now even with one it's not working

Comment: There is a limit of 10request/second for all webservices and also a daily limit of 2500 requests for geocoding. I'm afraid you have reached these limits and your access is blocked now(the `status`-argument of the geocoding-response may give you details)

Comment: also the API-console(usage quota) may give more details

Comment: I just checked that and that's not the problem. The website is still in development and I only have done about 800 requests in the past month so ...

Comment: .....you may have reached the 10requests/second-limit and you have been blocked temporarily. What returns the status of the geocoding-response?

Comment: It not a problem with the api or what so ever. I disovered that when i reload the page that contains the map, the markers aren't displayed but when i am redirected (eg: when i login and am redirected to that page) the markers are displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `loadSpots()` at the end of `initializeMaps()`, otherwise it may happen that  the `map` will be accessed before it's initialized.